# IOException File Copy unhandled. When uploading image from a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, image, ioexception

Help! I can't figure out how to close the file. It always gives me IOException file, something like **it is being used by another process**

Here's my code

```
private void uploadpic_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    open_dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

    open_dialog.Title = "Open picture";
    open_dialog.Filter = "JPEG (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif)|*.jpg";

    if (open_dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(open_dialog.FileName);
        uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        uploadpic_pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
    }
}

private void saveBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string targetPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "\\Pictures");
    string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, "Copied.jpg");

    if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
    }

    File.Copy(open_dialog.FileName, destFile, true);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Image myimage = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Pictures\Copied.jpg");

    uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImage = myimage;
    uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    uploadpic_pb.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
}
```

The exception returns

**The process cannot access the file 'C:\Pictures\Copied.jpg' because it is being used by another process.**

Comment: Your code makes little sense when combined with your description. 1) You never open any files in an way that needs closing (Image.FromFile and File.Copy don't leave files open). 2) You're saving the image into a MemoryStream only to discard that stream without using it (and it is guaranteed to be closed); that's pointless. 3) You don't tell where where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: even if i remove the memory stream the result will still be the same. The IOException always points out on the File.Copy line.

Comment: Some things you might consider "fixing" anyways: 1) stop using `@"" + `; you don't go around adding 0 to every number you use. 2) use Path.Combine to join paths instead of concatenation.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can help me how to solve my problem? Because if youre just messing around telling that "fix youre code style" youre not helping.

Comment: @Holyoxx: I know it's frustrating but this is the kind of site where people are kind of robotic and show no tact. They help you for sure, but don't expect people to be kind. :( He does make some points though, try to get past the tone and focus on the subject. :)

Comment: @Holyoxx, let me get this right. The control flow is: 1. Form_Load, 2. uploadpic_btn_Click, 3. saveBTN_Click?

Comment: @Sergio Tapia I'm not really looking for a kind people. :) Its just frustrating that some of them is telling to fix you're coding style, when they cannot even answer you're question.

Comment: @Holyoxx, I have tried the code in my instance of VS2008 and executing in the order specified, but I am not any exception. It is working as expected. Check whether you can copy the file in question in windows explorer.

Comment: @Devendera I can't get it to work :)

Comment: @Holyoxx, it will be helpful if you post the stack trace and inner exception of the exception you are encountering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Image.FromFile() puts a write lock on the file.  Form1_Load() thus puts a lock on Copied.jpg.  You then press the uploadpic_btn button to assign a new bitmap to the BackgroundImage property.  Next pressing saveBTN is however likely to fail the way you've written the code.  Copied.jpg is *still* locked, the Image object still exists.  It doesn't disappear until the garbage collector runs.

To avoid waiting for this, you'll have to dispose the image.  Fix:

```
    if (open_dialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        if (uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImage != null) uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImage.Dispose();
        uploadpic_pb.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(open_dialog.FileName);
        // etc...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  This had bugged me for ages as i was loading the image directly into the picturebox by using the myPicBox.Load(myFile) method, but putting the image into the BackgroundImage property and calling the dispose method cleared the file lock.  I was sure it was something to do with my picturebox locking the file, but could not find any information such as that which you gave in your response.  cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try using a class level variable for filename instead of targetPath with may be appending a datetime to keep it unique. Keep overwrite = false in the File.copy and see if it works. This is just a test to see that you Copied.Jpg file is in use.

Also - compile the solution in release mode and try running from EXE directly from bin  instead of Visual Studio. Sometime the Visual Studio helper process blocks the files.